# What is the table that logs metrics in Azure

Tags: azure

Azure VM's shows below charts in the overview tab. I would like to know the source table for these metrics so that I can customize and query them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above I believe Log Analytics is the source...specifically query the AzureDiagnostic Table here is a query to get you started:

```
 AzureDiagnostics
| where  ResourceProvider =="Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get them in Azure Monitor. Take a look on the Virtual Machine metrics:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/vminsights-performance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [log-analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-portal) , which will have all the metrics of the VM in the table format, here you can find how to find queries to get cutomized results for the particular [`VM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/get-started-queries)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need, you can view can data using log analytics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-azurevm#view-data-collected